# Open modal ViewController in window with my sizes

Tags: ios, swift, modalviewcontroller

How can I open modal ViewController in window with my sizes?

**I tried to use it, but it does not work**

```
modalViewController?.view.superview?.frame = CGRect(x:162, y: 333, width: 700,height: 700)
//
modalViewController?.view.superview?.center = self.view.center
```

**Code:**

```
let modalViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Clipboard") as? ClipboardViewController
    modalViewController?.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    self.present(modalViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Example:**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
let modalViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Clipboard") as? ClipboardViewController
modalViewController?.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
self.present(modalViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
modalViewController!.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 700, height: 700)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on an iPad you can do it by setting the preferred content size of the view controller, programmatically or in the storyboard.
But I would suggest you to use [presentation controllers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipresentationcontroller).
By using them you can return the size or the inset that you prefer.
Here the code of one of mine.

```
class PGSHelpPresentationController: UIPresentationController {
    // The dimming view is the view the you have around the the content of the view controller you want to present
    let dimmingView = UIView()

    override init(presentedViewController: UIViewController, presenting presentingViewController: UIViewController?) {
        super.init(presentedViewController: presentedViewController, presenting: presentingViewController)
        // here the dimming view is white with an alpha of 0.5
        dimmingView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)
    }

    override public func presentationTransitionWillBegin() {
        // Here I'm setting the initial properties of the dimming view (alpha and size)
        dimmingView.frame = containerView!.bounds
        dimmingView.alpha = 0.0
        containerView!.insertSubview(dimmingView, at: 0)
        //Here I'm asking to animate the change of alpha along with the transition animation of the view controller 
        presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: {
            context in
            self.dimmingView.alpha = 1.0
            },
            completion: nil)
    }

    override public func dismissalTransitionWillBegin() { //Here I'm asking that once the dismissal begin I'd like also that the the dimming view refers to sully transparent
        presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: {
            context in
            self.dimmingView.alpha = 0.0
            },
            completion: {
                context in
                self.dimmingView.removeFromSuperview()
        })
    }
   //Here I'm setting the size of the view controller that it should be displayed with an inset of 20pt
    override public var frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView: CGRect {
        return containerView!.bounds.insetBy(dx: 20, dy: 20)
    }

    override public func containerViewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        dimmingView.frame = containerView!.bounds
        presentedView!.frame = frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView
    }

}
```

Now I can create a custom animation, this a simple slide In transition:

```
class PGSBouncyViewControllerAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    public func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.8
    }

    public func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        if let presentedView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.to) {
            let centre = presentedView.center
            presentedView.center = CGPoint(x:centre.x,y: -presentedView.bounds.size.height)
            transitionContext.containerView.addSubview(presentedView)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: self.transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), animations: { () -> Void in
                presentedView.center = centre
            }, completion: { _ in
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)

            })

        }
    }
}
```

Now I create the transition delegate, the object that manages the transitions by returning the presentation controller and the custom animation.

```
public class PGSHelpTransitioningDelegate: NSObject, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    public func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
        return PGSHelpPresentationController(presentedViewController: presented,
                                             presenting: presenting)
    }

    public func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return PGSBouncyViewControllerAnimator()
    }

}
```

If you want to present your custom view controller, just create the transition delegate as a property(`lazy var bouncyTransitioningDelegate = PGSHelpTransitioningDelegate()`
) in the presenting view controller and do that:

```
let busyViewController = BusyViewController()
            busyViewController.transitioningDelegate = bouncyTransitioningDelegate
            busyViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
```